# preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation flag not working on iphoneX

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iphone-x

I've an app where all `View Controllers` run in portrait mode. I want one screen to show in landscape mode. So I'm using this code to present it in landscape:

```
override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation  {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
```

This view controller is being present on a base screen. This is working fine on all devices except iPhone X. If I return  `UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait` from `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` it works fine.

I'm not sure how to show this particular view controller in landscape mode on iPhone X. I would really appreciate any help.